# Interpolate doesn't work for numpy percentile

Tags: python, numpy, percentile

I'm trying to use the midpoint interpolation when using np.percentile and it gives me the error:
TypeError: percentile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interpolation'
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Same error message 7 years later. It's logged on [GitHub](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/21184). Up-grading to Numpy 1.22 did not solve the issue for me. Will try to use pandas function.

Answer (score 3):

It is says in [the documentation of `np.percentile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.9.1/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) that the `interpolation` argument was added in Numpy version 1.9.0. Based on the error message, I think you need to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks I updated to a newer version and that fixed it.

Comment: I have version 1.11.0, and I'm getting this error, only for the `quantile` function, not the `percentile` function. Any other ideas?

Comment: NVM. Figured it out: old version of `pandas`. Switched to `numpy.percentile` and it worked.